# I have an SCNScene instance. How do I extract each SCNGeometry instance?

Tags: scenekit, scnscene

In a `Metal` app written in `Swift` I want to extract the `SCNGeometry` instances from an `SCNScene` instance to go on and build `MDLMesh`'s. I see no API call that pulls out the geometry (similarly for cameras, and lights). How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the scene's root node's child nodes. For each node, extract its `geometry` or `camera` property (it could have both). See `SCNNode` documentation.

Comment: Thanks Hal. I tried traversing the MDLAsset and that was painful. I think thie SCNScene route will work better for me. Cheers,